# Convex in every argument but not convex

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Suppose $f(x_1, \dots, x_n): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Is there an example of such $f$ that is convex in every argument and not convex? Are there any additional conditions, under which 'marginal' convexity would be sufficient to call $f$ convex?

Comment: Duplicate of [Proof that a coordinate-wise convex function is convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211531/proof-that-a-coordinate-wise-convex-function-is-convex). See also [Convexity definition confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738676/convexity-definition-confusion).

Comment: Convexity along the axes is too little for the function for the overall convexity. To be convex the function must be convex not only along the axes, but along *all lines* in the domain.